# how can I update the event trigger?

Tags: postgresql

I create event trigger:

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_event_begin ON ddl_command_start EXECUTE PROCEDURE event_trigger_begin();
```

later I need to change the event or procedure. Now, I have to do so:

```
DROP EVENT TRIGGER tr_event_begin;
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_event_begin ON ddl_command_end EXECUTE PROCEDURE myProc();
```

how to do it differently? Without removing the trigger, update it... sql only.

Comment: modify existinf function instead - to change the functionality... no way around as no `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` statement

Comment: [**ALTER EVENT TRIGGER**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altereventtrigger.html) ??

Comment: ALTER EVENT TRIGGER - it's clear, how I can change the procedure or event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proposal is the most elegant way to do it.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altereventtrigger.html